# how to inject springbean to a struts intercepter..is it possible

Tags: spring, struts2

I am having a used defined intercepter,from the intercepter i want to make a db call through DAO layer, so how can i inject spring bean to struts intercepter.is it possible to inject spring bean to a struts intercepter
can any one suggest any idea on this.

Comment: Have you tried to inject it? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since there is no need to declare the Interceptor as Spring bean, I striked the unnecessary parts. Thanks to @AleksandrM for testing it.

---

Exactly the way you do with Actions <strike>, with (if I remember well) the exception of declaring it in beans.xml because Interceptors don't extend ActionSupport (that is autowired by default)</strike> .

web.xml

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```xml
<bean id="daoServiceBean" 
   class="org.foo.bar.business.dao.DaoService"/>
```

```
<bean id="myInterceptorBean" 
   class="org.foo.bar.presentation.interceptors.MyInterceptor"/>
```

Struts.xml

```xml
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />

<package ...>
    <interceptors>
```

```
        <interceptor name="myInterceptor" class="myInterceptorBean" />
```

```
        <interceptor name="myInterceptor" 
                    class="org.foo.bar.presentation.interceptors.MyInterceptor"/>
```

MyInterceptor.java

```java
private DaoService daoServiceBean; // Autowired by Spring
```

Also read:

- [Spring Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html)
- [Spring and Struts2](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring.html)

Comment: I think that should work w/o explicitly defining interceptor as a bean.

Comment: Yeah, but I wasn't sure. In the documentation is always reported ActionSupport, but in the end, the ObjectFactory is Spring...

Comment: Then 1) he hasn't even tried in Interceptor, or 2) he has config problems preventing injection to work on Actions too.