# integrate struts2 and spring plugin

Tags: spring, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

I try to develop a web application (Struts 2, Spring, Hibernate) using Maven, in eclipse.
I first create a simple Maven project, I joined Struts2, and everything goes perfectly. When I tried to integrate Spring and struts2-spring-plugin, I always have a 404 error.
Once I remove the dependence of struts2-spring-plugin my pom.xml, the application running again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.struts </groupId>
    <artifactId> struts2-spring-plugin </artifactId>
    <version> 2.3.16.3 </version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you get some errors? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26907334/1654265, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28808488/1654265

Comment: @Majda Elmari, can you add to your question other dependencies you have in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have already defined the object mapper like explained in the [struts2 spring plugin documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html)?

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
  ... 
</struts>
```

If you have defined it would be great if you could provide some more details about your config and your log messages.

Comment: Doesn't the Spring plugin set the object factory automatically? I don't recall having to set it by hand.

Comment: Dave you are right, this setting is not always necessary "If you are using more than one object factory, * you will need to set the struts.objectFactory property". But this and the missing listener are the must error root causes for this kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

you are not forced to add struts2-spring-plugin to work wirh spring, hibernate and struts. I work with project containing spring, struts2, hibernate and spring security and i dont have a configuration problem. You just should keep attention to the versions. Spring version should be the same to spring security version, but for struts 2 and hibernate there is no conflicts.